# SOAPUI - configure endpoints and resources for TestCase/TestSuite

Tags: soapui

Is there a way to configure the resource/method used by requests in tests on a test case, test suite or even project level in *SOAPUI (free)*?

*We have the following use case:* 
The same REST service running on different servers(potentially different versions) and slightly different resource paths depending on configuration. 
For e.g. `http://server1/myRest` or `http://server2/theRest` etc.

We would like to be able to run our test suites and test cases against those different endpoint/resource combinations. 
So far, the only way we found to change the endpoint is at test case level using the *Test Case editor* and to change the resource/method at test step level.

Clearly, it's not an option to duplicate all test cases / test suites for each endpoint / resource path combination or to create projects for that.

Is there a simple way to achieve that using `SOAPUI (free)`?

Comment: Have you considered to execute the tests programmatically? E.g. https://pritikaur23.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/saving-a-soapui-project-and-sending-requests-using-soapui-api/

Comment: @MusterMark that could be an option if there is no other way. But we'd prefer to be able to do that with the GUI because the intention is to also provide the project to test department which then can adapt and extend tests to theis needs. I doubt they'd like to struggle with code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We were able to find a solution to our problems, the key is to use project level properties.

### Endpoint

Basically, there are 2 ways for doing this.

#### With properties

1. Open the project view for your project and add a property named *ServiceEndpoint* (or any other name you want to use). Value is the host name, e.g. *server1:8090*
2. Open the service viewer for your service. On Tab *Service Endpoints*, add an endpoint *http://${#Project#ServiceEndpoint}*
3. Still in the service viewer, click the *Assign* button, select to which requests (all requests, test requests, both ...) you want to assign the endpoint to.

Now you only need to modify the project level property if you want to use another endpoint

#### Without properties

1. Use the service viewer to add the endpoints you need to use (see point 2 above)
2. Assign the endpoint you want to use (see point 3 above)

### Resource path

1. Use the project view to define a property *ResourcePath*
2. Add a new resource, define */{ServicePath}* as the resource path
3. Open the resource in the resource viewer. You will see that a parameter with name *ServicePath* with stlye TEMPLATE was added. Give it the value ${#Project#ResourcePath}
4. Use this resource in your test suites / test cases

Now you only need to modify the project level property to change the resource path.

You can also define multiple path components, e.g. */{serviceName}/{methodName}* or something similar. Of course you would need 2 variables for that.

**Note:** if the value of your path property contains a /, you will need to edit the SOAP UI *HTTP Settings* in the preferences and check the *Pre-Encoded Endpoints* checkbox, otherwise it won't work because the / will be URL encoded

Comment: @SiKing well, that part of the documentation merely shows how to define a project level property for an endpoint and how it can be used. What I wrote describes the steps to achieve that in more detail and additionally describes how to create a parametrised resource. I could find no hint for that in the SOAPUI docs. But thank your for posting a link to that part of the docs, I could have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double Click on Endpoint URL at left below project from Navigator
2. Go to Service Endpoints
3. Click on Add or + symbol
4. Enter end points
5. Click on Assign->All request with no end point

Prerequisite:Empty the url wherever you need this change to be applied.